# Show directory path with only files present in them

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

This is the folder structure that I have.
[image]

Using the find command `find . -type d` in `root` folder gives me the following result

Result

```
./folder1
./folder1/folder2
./folder1/folder2/folder3
```

However, I want the result to be only `./folder1/folder2/folder3`. i.e only print the result if there's a file of type `.txt` present inside.

Can someone help with this scenario? Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' |
sed 's=/[^/]*\.txt$==' |
sort -u
```

Find all `.txt` files, remove file names with `sed` to get the parent directories only, then `sort -u` to remove duplicates.

This won’t work on file names/paths that contain a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `find` command that finds all the `*.txt` files and then it gets unique their parent directory names:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c '
for f; do
   f="${f#.}"
   printf "%s\0" "$PWD${f%/*}"
done
' _ {} + | awk -v RS='\0' '!seen[$0]++'
```

- We are using `printf "%s\0"` to address directory names with newlines, spaces and glob characters.
- Using gnu-awk to get only unique directory names printed

Answer (score 1):

Using Associative [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) and [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A uniq_path

while IFS= read -rd '' files; do
  path_name=${files%/*}
  if ((!uniq_path["$path_name"]++)); then
    printf '%s\n' "$path_name"
  fi
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0)
```

---

Check the value of `uniq_path`

```
declare -p uniq_path
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this POSIX one?

```
find root -type f -name '*.txt' -exec dirname {} \; | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

** adds a trailing `\n` after each directory path*

** breaks when a directory in a path has a `\n` in its name*

Or this BSD/GNU one?

```
find root -type f -name '*.txt' -exec dirname {} \; -exec printf '\0' \; | sort -z -u
```

** adds a trailing `\n\0` after each directory path*